# How do I pass a pointer to a struct from a library function back into my main.c program?

Tags: c

I have a function and a struct defined in my library. I want the function to return a pointer to the struct. When I try to compile the program and the library I get the following error:

```
error: incomplete definition of type 'struct _bmpfile'
    printf("file size: %d", bmp->header.filesz);
                            ~~~^
/usr/local/include/bmpfile.h:116:16: note: forward declaration of 'struct _bmpfile'
```

typedef struct _bmpfile bmpfile_t;

The struct is declared in bmpfile.h and then defined in bmpfile.c. My program, main.c, calls the following function which should return a bmpfile_t:

```
bmp = bmp_create_from_file(filename);

bmpfile_t*
bmp_create_from_file(const char *filename)
{
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) perror("error");

    bmpfile_t *bmp = (bmpfile_t *)malloc(sizeof(bmpfile_t));

    bmp_get_header_from_file(fp, bmp);
    bmp_get_dib_from_file(fp, bmp);
    bmp_get_pixels_from_file(fp, bmp);
    fclose(fp);
    return bmp;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that identifiers ending in `_t` are reserved by POSIX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `printf` call will need a full definition of the struct before it can access the members.

It's common for libraries to declare only the name of the struct in the header file, so files including the header can manipulate pointers to the type without knowing the contents. The struct is considered *opaque*. This is roughly the C equivalent to declaring all members *private.*

<del>For hacking purposes, you can paste the structure definition into your main file and peek at the values in the struct. But for "production" code, don't ever do this, period, end-of-sentence (unless you have a really really really good reason, but be prepared to explain this reason to anyone who may see the code!).</del>

As paulsm4 says, you can use `bmp_header_t bmp_get_header(bmpfile_t *bmp);` to get a header object that you can access.

Comment: I am working with the libbmp library. Any idea why they would define most the structs in the .h, but then define the _bmpfile struct in the .c?

Comment: The usual reason is "information hiding". *You don't need to know* what's in those structs in order to use them. You're expected to use the struct just as an opaque *handle* type and pass it to the various functions that operate on it.

Comment: The point is that you don't *NEED* the "hacking" workaround. In version libbmp v0.1.3 (the version I have), you should use `bmp_get_header()`, declared in `bmpfile.h`.  It's possible `bmp_get_header_from_file(fp, bmp)` (not present in my version) might also accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Thanks. I double-checked at http://code.google.com/p/libbmp/source/browse/trunk/src/bmpfile.h and you're right. Updated + credited.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that bmpfile_t is declared as an "opaque struct".

Solution: simply call `bmp_get_header()`